# Can anyone give me any hints on this combinatorial graph theory problem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a graph $G$ with $n$ vertices and minimal degree $d$, prove there exists a set $X$ with at most $\frac{n(1+\log(d+1))}{d+1}$ vertices such that every vertex not in $X$ is connected to at least one vertex in $X$.

So I've been stuck on this question for quite a while and don't seem to have any useful insight. I can get a lower bound for the number of vertices as $\frac{n-1}{d}$ using an averaging argument but do not know how to get an upper bound.

Another approach was to consider a random induced subgraph of G where each vertex survives independently with probability $p$, then use the fact that if the set of vertices deleted/$X$ satisfies the conditions, then the degree of each remaining vertex must fall by at least one.

This allows you to compute the expected number of vertices $|V|$ whose degree remains unchanged as
$$\mathbb{E}[|V|]=\sum_{v_i}p^{d(v_i)}$$
where the sum is over the vertices that survive.
But I can't seem to use this to obtain any sort of bound on $|X|$.
Any hints or corrections would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here's a method which does not work, because it gives a slightly worse $\log$ factor. Suppose you choose $k$ vertices with replacement to include in $X$, each chosen uniformly at random from $V(G)$. For any $v\in V(G)$, the probability that neither $v$ nor any of $v$'s neighbors were included in $X$ is $(1-(d+1)/n)^k$, so the expected number of unsatisfied vertices is $n(1-(d+1)/n)^k$. Setting this less than $1$, you get $k>\frac{\log n}{-\log(1-(d+1)/n)}$. Since $-\log(1-x)\approx x$, this gives $k\approx  \frac{n}{d+1}\log n$, which is not quite what you want.

Comment: I think your method gives $\mathbb{E}[|V'|]=\sum_{v \in V(G)}(1-\frac{d(v)+1}{n})^k$. So maybe using a stronger inequality would give the result. Where $V'$ is the set of unsatisfied vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/33736/50404) on the theoretical computer science stack exchange gives a citation to Theorem 1.2.2 in *The Probabilistic Method* by Alon and Spencer, which solves your problem exactly.

As you suggested, you start by including each vertex in $X$ with probability $p$, independently of other vertices. Given $X$, let $Y$ be the set of vertices which are not in $X$ and have no neighbors in $X$. The key idea is to use $X\cup Y$ as the dominating set.

Note $E|X|=np$, and $E|Y|\le n(1-p)^{d+1}$, so there certainly exists a dominating set of size at most $np+n(1-p)^{d+1}$. Using the inequality $1-x\le e^{-x}$, the size is at most
$$
np + ne^{-p(d+1)}.
$$
All that remains is to choose the value of $p$ which minimizes the above expression, via the usual calculus method. I leave that part to you.